# Vue.js change data in entire other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My vue.js component structure looks like this:

```
<wrapper>
    <component-one></component-one>
    <component-two></component-two>
</wrapper>
```

I need to set data that I receive in `component-one` in `component-two`.

I am using [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/) so I can only change/add code to `component-one` I can't add a listener to `component-two` because it lives in my `node_modules` map.

Is there some other trick I can do, so I can achieve this?

Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could share a value between the two components like this:

```
<wrapper>
  <component-one model="data"></component-one>
  <component-two model="data"></component-two>
</wrapper>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change anything to `component-two`. I need something like `Vue.set('component-name').data('name').value('blablabla');`